Errors attaching metadata to corpus
I am trying to generate a corpus with two documents: one is responses of participants characterized as "supporters" and one is responses of "non-supporters". I've entered this as variable "group" and am trying to assign it as metadata in my corpus. This approach worked earlier, but now I keep getting errors. Any ideas to resolve this error? Or, alternatively, is there a better approach to do this?
> qualitative %>% filter(!is.na(altOpenEnded))
>
> table(qualitative$group)

non-supporters     supporters 
          2025            197 
> 
> # Create a corpus with the responses
> corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(qualitative$altOpenEnded))
> 
> # Preprocess the corpus
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)  # Convert to lowercase
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)  # Remove punctuation
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)  # Remove numbers
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))  # Remove English stopwords
> corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)  # Strip whitespace
> 
> # Attach metadata to the corpus
> meta(corpus, "group") <- qualitative$group
Error in UseMethod("meta<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'meta<-' applied to an object of class "c('VCorpus', 'Corpus')"

If I try to skip this step and just create a dtm, I get an error saying it's a character object
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus) Error in UseMethod("meta", x) :  no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character" 

What does environment(meta) return?

@MrFlick  'environment: namespace:NLP'

Well, meta() seems to be a function in both the tm package and the NLP package. It seems you are trying to use the tm version but NLP was the last package loaded. Rather than just meta(), try using tm::meta() to get the version you want.
